# How can I convert graphic text to attribute field within polygon that encloses it

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, annotation, graphics

I was able to convert graphic polygons to GDB. Similarly, I can convert the graphic text to annotation within same GDB. But I need to have that text as an attribute or field within the polygon table. How can I do this?

The graphic text was drawn within the polygons.

Comment: Use 'Convert Graphics To Features' http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000008000000

Answer (score 1):

Add X and Y field to annotations. Populate them with coordinates of centroid (sometimes lower left corner works better). Convert annotation table to points. Spatially join polygons to points. Assume there is one annotation per polygon.